# How do I view the Datadog dashboards I have created

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I created a Datadog dashboard to test a metric, closed the window and now I'd like to find the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not give the dashboard a title it will have a default title which you can search for. The default title has this form:

```
<YOUR NAME>'s Dashboard <DATE AND TIME YOU CREATED THE DASHBOARD>
```

The date you created dashboard is in the form: abbreviated month (e.g. Feb instead of February), abbreviated day (e.g. Tue instead of Tuesday), Time (e.g. 5:37:33 pm).

For example:

```
Lucy's Dashboard Tue, Feb 7, 5:27:32 pm
```